# Meteor get ID of template parent

Tags: meteor

I have two Collection : a collection A which include array of B ids.

**Template A :**

```
<template name="templateA">
  Name : {{name}} - {{_id}}
  {{#each allBsOfThisA}}
      {{> Bdetail}}
  {{/each}}
  <a href="{{pathFor 'Bsubmit'}}">Add B for this A</a>
</template>
```

Note : in this templateA, I list all A and their detail informations. At bottom of the A, I putted a link to add a B.

**Template of Bsubmit :**

```
<div class="form-group {{errorClass 'nameOfB'}}">
  <label class="control-label" for="nameOfB">nameOfB</label>
  <div class="controls">
      <input name="nameOfB" id="nameOfB" type="text" value="" placeholder="nameOfB" class="form-control"/>
      <span class="help-block">{{errorMessage 'nameOfB'}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

On the Bsubmit script : I want to get the ID of A. I tried with **template.data._id** but it's not working :

```
Template.Bsubmit.events({'submit form': function(e, template) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
     console.log("template.data._id: " + template.data._id);
       var B = {
         name: $(e.target).find('[name=name]').val(),
         AId : template.data._id
       };   
  } 
});
```

***EDIT :***

**BSubmit's  iron-router part :**

```
Router.route('Bsubmit ', {name: 'Bsubmit '});
```

Comment: Template.parentData()._id

Comment: How do you set the data context for `dealSubmit`?

Comment: Don't seem to work for Template.parentData()._id : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null.

Comment: I edited for dealSubmit : it's Bsubmit

Comment: You define the events on Bsubmit, but you never use the template Bsubmit? Where is that coming from?

Comment: I mixed Bsubmit and submitB in the example but it reference the same template. I edited for better understanding.

Comment: Still. Either the router is missing (since you use pathFor I assume you use iron:router) or you aren't using the template (no {{> Bsubmit }}). So we can't really help

Comment: Yes I use iron-router. I edited first post.

Comment: `parentData()` is used for embedded templates, like `{{>Bdetail}}`. Since Bsubmit is another route you don't have any associated data of A in there. Either you have to pass the id with the route or you have to find A somewhere in the Bsubmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the template nor the route does know about the A-instance of the other template/route.

So one solution would be to pass the id to the route, which allows you to fetch the instance or use the id directly:

## Template:

```
<template name="templateA">
   Name : {{name}} - {{_id}}
   {{#each allBsOfThisA}}
      {{> Bdetail}}
   {{/each}}
   <a href="{{pathFor 'Bsubmit' _id=_id}}">Add B for this A</a>
</template>
```

## Route:

[More information about passing arguments to a route](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router#quick-start)

```
Router.route('/Bsubmit/:_id', function () {
  var a = A.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  this.render('Bsubmit', {data: a});
});
```

Then you could use template.data._id in the event.

Another solution would be to embed the form into the other view, so you can access the data of the parent template in there ([documentation of parentData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata)).